# 500 Internal Server Error in codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, internal-server-error

I am using CodeIgniter 3.

My `.htaccess` file contains the following.

I  am getting 500 Internal Server Error .

I tried renaming the `.htaccess` file , i got 404 .

I want to see the Apache error log. but i only have one folder in my root directory, which is `public_html` where my    project files are based at.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase http://www.xyzsolutions.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

in my `config.php`  i have

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.xyzsolutions.com/'; 

$config['index_page'] = ' ';
```

in database.php

```
'hostname' => 'http://www.xyzsolutions.com/',
```

I cannot find `/var/log/httpd/error_log`
how to get this , so that i can view the Apache error log ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
I solved the issue , changed my .htaccess to

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

In config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.xyzsolutions.com/';

```
And As i am using Codeigniter version 3

The Controllers and model files names should start with an upper case,

Eg:

models/User_model.php
controllers/Welcome.php 

I named my files with lower case( starting letter )so i was getting 404.

Lower case thing worked in localhost , but in server it will not work
```

Answer (score 2):

In your database.php change your hostname to 'localhost'

```
$config['hostname'] => 'localhost';
```

In your .htaccess change the RewriteBase to

```
RewriteBase /
```

Try also to leave the config['base_url'] empty

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
```